# Download link or Downloading link?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

Well today I was about to post a video on YouTube and I hesitate on whether to type:

> "Download link provided by request"

or

> "Downloading link provided by request"

Which one is the right phrase to be grammatical here?

P.S
I know the Internet is the Internet and we all break grammar rules but I was thinking to post this video on Facebook later on and I don't want my friends to be thinking this foo knows no English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the correct (or certainly the most common) phrase is "Download Link provided by request". Just look through many youtube comments and the 1st one (Download) is prevalent. In my experience it has always been "Download Link". No one would question your proficiency in English for saying that.